# Can Firefox be switched to a 'Long Term Support' update channel?

Tags: firefox, automatic-update

If Firefox 10 is to be the new 'Long Term Support' release (meaning the version is supported for 12 months instead of only a few weeks at a time) and Firefox 3.6 support is being discontinued in April, is it possible to set a Firefox 10 installation to a 'Long Term Support' update channel instead of the default 'Release' channel?

I would like users to benefit from the automatic/silent update mechanism, but only to download and install patches, not whole version updates from the rapid release schedule (Firefox 11-16).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can download ESR version of Firefox 10 here:
http://www.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/organizations/all.html

And just in case here is Thunderbird ESR:
http://www.mozilla.org/en-US/thunderbird/organizations/all-esr.html

Comment: After backing up it seems the ESR build installs cleanly over FF10 (just in time to head off the automatic attempt to update to FF11), preserving the users settings, history, extensions, etc. After installation it does indeed say "no updates" instead of trying to update to FF11 and there is a huge "ESR" in the about dialog. Still haven't tested with a direct upgrade from FF3.6 yet but I expect the same result.